# What are the differences between Bytenet and Wavenet?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, comparison, machine-translation

I recently read [Bytenet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.10099) and [Wavenet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.03499) and I was curious why the first model is not as popular as the second. From my understanding, Bytenet can be seen as a seq2seq model where the encoder and the decoder are similar to Wavenet. Following the trends from NLP where seq2seq models seem to perform better, I find it strange that I couldn't find any paper that compares the two. Are there any drawbacks of Bytenet over Wavenet other than the computation time?

Comment: Have you seen this thread https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/ai4vro/d_anyone_here_use_bytenet_like_architecture_for/ ?

Comment: David Pollack mentions some characteristics of the two models in his master's thesis: "Musical Genre Classification of Audio" at https://edoc.hu-berlin.de/bitstream/handle/18452/20012/master_pollack_david.pdf?sequence=7

Answer (score 0):

My conclusion is the same as yours that there doesn't seem to be any published comparison of the two models.  ByteNet is computationally expensive and requires a lot of parameters.  WaveNet improves on ByteNet's efficiency, as you mentioned, and I believe that is the main difference.